# Django login_required passes but then user.is_authenticated fails in the template (??)

Tags: django, templates, login-required, render-to-response

This view function:

```
@login_required 
def dashboard(request):
    from myproject.myapp.models import UserProfile
    k = UserProfile.objects.get( user=request.user.pk ).known

    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', {'KNOWN': k, , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Passes to this template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
    Login link
{% endif %}
    {{ KNOWN }}
```

1. I have already logged in.
2. Page does not redirect to LOGIN_URL (so therefore @login_required thinks im logged in I guess)
3. {{ KNOWN }} renders perfectly OK
4. {{ user.username }} doesn't appear

How is this possible? Surely if login_required works, and it managed to grab KNOWN, therefore user *must* exist somewhere?
How can I debug this?

:-)

---

UPDATE:
If I remove:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.request',)
```

From settings, it works.
However, by removing that, other pages which use {{ request.get_full_path }} in templates don't load.
Eeek.

---

UPDATE 2:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.request",)
```

If you just add the request line on its own, it disables all the others which are defaults. D'Oh!

---

UPDATE 3: Thought that would fix it, unfortunately still not working.

---

UPDATE 4: Spotted typo elsewhere, can confirm that Mark Lavin's answer fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.request',)` then you are removing all the default context processors in particular `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` which adds `user` to the context. You should instead use

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep django.core.context_processors.request, it allows to use the {{ request }} in templates.

The request object features a user property which should correspond to the user requesting the page.

Try this, it should work for you too:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    you're authenticated as {{ request.user.username }}
{% else %}
    i'm a guest
{% endif %}
```